# One-click web site backup with asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, backup

I want to backup my web site regularly but instead of backup my files via ftp program I want a one-click solution which will copy all my files and zip them and allow to download. Can this be done with asp.net at same web site or I have to write a .net app for this purpose?

Comment: what type of backup, Database backup or the uploaded files in the site (I assumed users upload files in it).

Comment: Entire backup. Yes, there is a database and could be newly uploaded files. Like a simple CMS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Backup was very easy with [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/). Just give a directory name to backup and wait file to be downloaded. Even can set a password for the zip. I love open-source solutions.

```
using Ionic.Zip;

public void btnOneClickZip_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.BufferOutput = false;

    string archiveName = String.Format("backup-{0}.zip",
    DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss"));
    Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + archiveName);

    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        zip.AddDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Assets/Upload/"),
            "httpdocs/Assets/Upload");
        zip.AddDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"), "httpdocs/App_Data");

        zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
    }
    Response.Close();
}
```

Comment: But you omit `Database` backup, How to do entire backup?

Comment: You can do a sql backup to same app_data folder if your  sql is on the same server.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can do what you won, by this way.

Find a zip library like [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/Download.aspx) and you just programming to create a zip file and include the basic application path **HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath** including all paths.

Save this zip created file on a tempo dir and just download it.

This is a fast solution and maybe have some problems, for example probably fail to open locked files...

If you won to backup only your database, then you must do different thinks.

Hope this help.

Comment: @HasanGursoy thank you for the info, I will give it a try and see this lib. The other one I give you I use it all ready and works fine, but I will check the new one also.